# How to merge 2 Records in innoDB MySQL databases

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

This is related to [How to change ID in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717444/how-to-change-id-in-mysql/10718335#comment13919873_10718335)

I also have checked other questions and none are quite like this one.

As we know, innodb has a feature. If I want to channge an id of a record for example, then all other table that point to the previous ID will magically be updated.

What about if I want to MERGE 2 records?

Say I have 2 businesses.

They have 2 ID.

I want to merge them into one. I also want to use innodb awesome feature to automatically change things.

I can't just change one of the id to the other ID. Or can I?

What would you do to merge 2 simmilar records in database?

Of course what actually goes into the combined record will be business decisions.

Basically I just do not want to pin point all the other table one by one. I think on update rule is there for a reason. Is there a way where I just change slaveID to masterID, keep ALL data in master the same, and then have the database itself (rather than my program) to repoint all tables that point to slaveID to point to masterID? of course, records for slaveID will be gone anyway.

For example, with normal mysql engine, you can change ID, and then you have to go through all table that points to the old ID to point the new ID instead. With innodb, that repointing is done by the database engine itself. Which is kind of cool. Why would anyone use non innodb engine anyway.

I want to do the same but for merging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to set a records primary key to an already existing value will simply result in a key violation error. While this is simple on a first glance, it has a side effect: You can not use `ON UPDATE CASCADE` to merge two records - it will simply not work.

If you have the possibility to change the schema, you can use the old but good redirect-trick:

(Assuming your IDs are positive, maybe unsigend ints)

- add a field `redirect int not null default 0`
- Create a view:

.

```
CREATE VIEW tablename_view 
SELECT 
  -- repeat next line for every field apart from redirect
  IF(s.redirect>0,m.<fieldname>,s.<fieldname>
FROM tablename AS s
LEFT JOIN tablename AS m ON s.redirect=m.id
```

- When you merge a record (slave) into another record (master) run `UPDATE tablename SET redirect=<id_of_master> WHERE id=<id_of_slave>`
- Adapt your select queries to select from `tablename_view` instead of `tablename`
- Create and use a maintenance script to weed out merger slaves

Comment: So basically we got to go through all the table that point to the slave and repoint them to master?

Comment: If 'master' records have `redirect=<id_of_self>`, then the view would not need any of the `IF` expressions, but could instead simply `SELECT m.* FROM ...`.

Comment: In the maintenance script, this is what you do. The advantage is, that **after** redirection, but **before** maintenance you have both records, but only one actively used, so you have a perfect window of opportunity to do the merge by busines rules

Comment: Actually that's not the issue. Let's just say I do not need window of opportunity. I just do not want to pin point all the other table one by one. I think on update rule is there for a reason. Is there a way where I just change slaveID to masterID, keep ALL data in master the same, and then have the database itself (rather than my program) to repoint all tables that point to slaveID to point to masterID? of course, records for slaveID will be gone anyway.

Comment: @eggyal You are right, but the zero is typically chosen for safety and for easy inserting: When you insert with an `AUTO_INCREMENT` you need a `AFTER INSERT` trigger to fill the redirect, and if you update an ID, as the OQ seems to suggest, you are on thin ice: it is easy to forget to update the self-redirect.

Comment: @JimThio As I said in the first paragraph, this will not work: To have `ON UPDATE CASCADE` "automagically" update your foreign keys would mean to set the ID of the slave record to be set to the ID of the master record, but the IDs need to be unqiue for the "magic" to work.

Comment: Yes that's precisely why it doesn't work. So I need to basically make a program to pinpoint all those pointers to slaveID?

Comment: If the redirect method doesn't hurt your performance, you can just keep the redirected records and never need a maintenance script. Shot Version: **Redirect->No manual script, Real Merge->Needs manual script**