# How can I merge 2 rows in an innodb table

Tags: mysql, sql, merge, duplicates, innodb

I've taken over the development of a web app that uses a mysql innodb database. The client has a lot of duplicate records in the db on accident. I'm building a merge tool to keep one record and push the other's associated data to it.

So, for example because of a typo, I might have.

```
entity_id    entity_cat    common_name
--------------------------------------
abcdefg      customer      John Doe
hijklmn      customer      Jon Doe
```

I then have a bunch of tables that are linked to entity_id. I want to delete 'hijklmn', and have all of the associated data in other tables change their 'customer_entity_id' to 'abcdef'.

The problem is, the relationships all have on delete cascade. Is there any way for me to merge these two records without losing any data?

Comment: Would this be helpful:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/10734643/613247

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regards to your `ON DELETE CASCADE` issue, you can temporarily disable all foreign key constraints for the purpose of your query with the script template below:

```
ALTER TABLE `entities` NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL

-- commit query here

ALTER TABLE `entities` CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

Comment: No way! I'm going to go test that. Thanks! I'll mark this as answered after I try it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you update all of the records before you do the delete, then there shouldn't be any cascade at all:

```
update other_table_1 set entity_id='abcdefg' where entity_id='hijklmn';
update other_table_2 set entity_id='abcdefg' where entity_id='hijklmn';
update other_table_3 set entity_id='abcdefg' where entity_id='hijklmn';
...
delete from user_table where entity_id='abcdefg'
```

Comment: I tried that, but I was getting foreign key errors. They cascade on update.