# Complex mysql row merge with innodb database

Tags: mysql, merge, innodb, rows

This is a follow up to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851408/how-can-i-merge-2-rows-in-an-innodb-table). Please read that first.

I've got a complex situation on my hands, and I'm not sure how to deal with it. Basically, I have three tables that I need to merge data from.

entities

```
entity_id    entity_cat    common_name
--------------------------------------
abcdefg      customer      John Doe
hijklmn      customer      Jon Doe
```

jobs

```
job_nbr    customer_entity_id    address_nbr
--------------------------------------------
1          abcdefg               1
2          hijklmn               1
```

addresses

```
entity_id    address_nbr    ...
-------------------------------
abcdefg      1              etc
hijklmn      1              etc
```

Somehow, I need to merge the two entities. I'm going to get rid of 'hijklmn', but keep all of it's data. I'm updating jobs just fine, until I get to addresses. Addresses has two primary keys (entity_id and address_nbr). I need to merge the second row you see in the addresses table to look like this:

```
entity_id    address_nbr    ...
-------------------------------
abcdefg      1              etc
abcdefg      2              etc
```

And then I need to update jobs to look like this:

```
job_nbr    customer_entity_id    address_nbr
--------------------------------------------
1          abcdefg               1
2          abcdefg               2
```

I know how I would do it in theory, but I have no idea how to communicate this in sql nor where too look for answers.

Comment: Since `abcdefg` and `hijklmn` point to the same `address_nbr`, isn't it redundant to remap it?

Comment: The address_nbr is not unique across all addresses, just unique to each entity_id. When I merge, I need to increment the merging address numbers so they remain unique to the new entity.